# SQL to create a repeat of customers for each month period

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a table that is the result of a customer group for each date period. They have no relationship whatsoever.

So I have 36 months, and 10 customers.
What I want as the output is a single table that is 36 months for each customer, meaning I should end up with 360 rows, and two columns.

```
-- CREATE A TABLE of DATES - will produce 36 rows x 1 col
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20210701',
        @EndDate   DATE = '20240630';

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(month, 1, mydate) AS myDate
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  Dateadd(month, 1, mydate) <= @EndDate),
     dates
     AS (SELECT Eomonth(mydate) mydate
         FROM   cte),
     activities

     AS (SELECT 'whatever' as Whatever)


SELECT 
       mydate 
FROM   dates
```

Get the list of customers.

```
-- this will produce 1 column of 10 rows. 
select CustomerName from Customers where Region =3;
```

THE END RESULT I NEED

---

| MyDate | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-30 | Customer 1 |
| 2022-05-31 | Customer 1 |
| 2022-06-30 | Customer 1 |
| ..... | ....... |
| 2022-04-30 | Customer 2 |
| 2022-05-31 | Customer 2 |
| 2022-06-30 | Customer 2 |

How can I do this on SQL Server v11?

Comment: A [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) is designed for this

Comment: Are you looking for a *cross join*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *cross join* matches all rows from both inputs resulting in the product of all rows, eg

```
select *
from dates 
cross join (
    select 'customer1' Customer union all
    select 'customer2' Customer union all   
    select 'customer3' -- etc
)Customers
order by customer;
```

Comment: But then if I have 46,000 customers....? I know the actual end goal of the real world application will produce a table of many hundred thousands of rows.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance - if you have 10 customers and 36 dates this will give your desired 360 rows; if you have 46k customers in one resultset then you'll get 1.65m rows

Comment: Ah, yep worked it out. Thanks for that... first time using  a cross join